# User is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm attempting to create an eks cluster through the aws cli with the following commands:

```
aws eks create-cluster --name ekCsluster --role-arn arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/eksServiceRole --resources-vpc-config subnetIds=subnet-1,subnet-2,subnet-3,subnet-4,subnet-5,subnet-6,securityGroupIds=sg-1
```

And get the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateCluster operation: User: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/userName is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/eksServiceRole
```

However, I've created a permission policy, `AssumeEksServiceRole` and attached it directly to the user, `arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/userName`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/eksServiceRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the `eksServiceRole` role, I've defined the trust relationship as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/userName"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing? How can I go about debugging this error message? Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: In the ARNs you've got 000000... and 111111... - does that mean the user and the role are in *different AWS accounts*? That could probably cause quite a few issues. Can you try with a *user* in the same account as the *role*?

Comment: No, they're all the same account. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the user from the trust relationship (which is unnecessary anyways). AWS services don't play well when having a mix of accounts and service as principals in the trust relationship, for example, if you try to do that with CodeBuild it will complain saying it doesn't own the the principal.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can just use:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/eksServiceRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I use this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "CustomEditor",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Your entry in the `eksServiceRole` role is not necessary.